# What the correct way to find the transient equation of the latch circuit given below

Tags: circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, transient

So i have question i have found the transfer function for the of the given latch circuit, now i want to find the transient equation of the given transfer function, now i think the way i did this is not correct because the units are not matching i am getting frequency as unit  on the right hand side and unitless on left hand side [image]

Comment: This question looks like a repeat of the one you asked yesterday: [How to calculate the time constant of a simple cross coupled diff pair latch circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/683091/how-to-calculate-the-time-constant-of-a-simple-cross-coupled-diff-pair-latch-cir). Maybe you can explain why it's significantly different?

Comment: As your other question has no answers at this time, I would recommend editing the additional information (schematic and analysis; you can also format the equations as inline text) into that post.